# What's the best way to handle my app trying to use a screen when the Firestore trigger on the server hasn't finished doing its job?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database

Inside the app, the user creates a group. The app creates the appropriate Firestore record, then a Firestore trigger creates the node in Realtime Database to hold members and chats.

The problem is that when the app finishes creating the Firestore record, it opens up the screen for the newly created group and this screen tries to attach a listener to the chats node for that group, but the trigger hasn't yet finished doing its work. So the app receives this error:

> Unhandled Exception: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

This is because the permission to read the chats node is given by having the user's UID in the members node. So if this stuff hasn't been written yet, then the listener can't be attached.

What's a good way to handle this? I could add a 500 ms delay, but that seems like bad programming. Plus, when I deploy this app to production it's possible that the trigger takes a little bit longer than normal and therefore I'd be adding a 500 ms delay for no reason.

**The listener:**

```
void getChatListener() async {
    final node = 'group/groupID1/chats';
    _groupChatRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref(node);

    _chatsSubscription = _groupChatRef.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      dataList = [];

      for (final child in event.snapshot.children) {
        dataList.add(child.value);
      }

      setState(() {
        chats = dataList;
      });

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, in the front end, set a real-time listener to the initial Firestore document that triggered the Cloud Function.

Then, in the Cloud Function, when all the (actual) work is complete you update a flag in the Firestore document (e.g. a field `completed` that you pass to `true`).

The listener in the front end detects it. You then

1. Attach the listener to the chat node for the group
2. [Detach the Firestore listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener)

In other words, you implement a way for the front end to know when the background triggered Cloud Function has completed. You can find a more or less similar example in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-create-an-image-translation-web-app-in-25-lines-of-code-e67460208d29).

---

**Another** totally different approach would be to use a [Callable Cloud function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd) instead of a background triggered one to create the RTDB node. When the Cloud Function job is complete you send back a *success* flag to the front end.

The flow would be:

1. The app creates the appropriate Firestore document
2. The app calls the Callable CF passing the Firestore document ID
3. The Callable CF creates the RTDB node and returns a *success* flag to the front end
4. The app attaches a listener to the chats node for that group

It is actually a cleaner solution than the first one described above (and you avoid some Firestore reads)

Comment: I went with the 2nd option. Thanks!